# I can't set TextView layout_height to wrap content

Tags: android, layout, textview, height

This is my code:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_column="2"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In this example there is only 2 lines of text visible but there are more lines than 2. How can I set height of this TextView to wrap content instead of overflowing it?

Comment: use multiline textviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add padding to textview:

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

For example:

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your textview:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a multi line textbox for defined text use

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

But it is not good for long text. because sometimes it will overflow your layout. so use **scrollable textview** is most preferable

```
android:maxLines = "4"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this to the textview

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:lines="3"
```